# XPath - select all after specific tag

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to put into a string the HTML after a `h1` tag up until the next `h1` tag, and then continue.

For example, here is the HTML:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 2</h1>
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
<p>Paragraph<img /></p>
```

And from this I am trying to create this array:

```
array(
  0 => '<p>Paragraph</p><ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph</p>',
  1 => '<ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph<img /></p>'
)
```

What would be the XPath query to select all content after the `h1` tag up until the next, and so on?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

UPDATE:

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is, using PHP, create this format of an array:

```
array(
  'headings' => array(
      1 => '<h1>Heading</h1>',
      2 => '<h1>Heading 2</h1>'
  ),
  'content'  => array(
      1 => '<p>Paragraph</p><ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph</p>',
      2 => '<ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph<img /></p>'
  )
)
```

Comment: I Think this can helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276753/xpath-select-first-element-after-some-other-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this :)

```
$html = '<h1>Heading</h1><p>Paragraph</p><ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph</p><h1>Heading 2</h1><ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph<img /></p>';

$dom_document = new DOMDocument();

$dom_document->loadHTML($html);
$dom_document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

//use DOMXpath to navigate the html with the DOM
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

$elements = $dom_xpath->query("/html/body/*");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element->nodeName == 'h1') {
            $i++;
            $array['headings'][$i] = $dom_document->saveHtml($element);
            continue;
        } else {
            $array['content'][$i] .= $dom_document->saveHtml($element);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

NOTE: should you be using PHP 5.2 then replace:

```
$array['headings'][$i] = $dom_document->saveHtml($element);
```

and

```
$array['content'][$i] .= $dom_document->saveHtml($element);
```

with:

```
$array['headings'][$i] = $dom_document->saveXml($element);
$array['content'][$i] .= $dom_document->saveXml($element);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to do that.

Assuming your code is placed in `$code`:

```
$code = <<<'CODE'
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 2</h1>
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
<p>Paragraph<img /></p>
CODE;
```

**Solution:**

```
// Content array...
$content = array_map(
    function ($element) {
        return preg_replace('/\>\s+\</', '><', $element);
    },
    preg_split('/\<h1\>[^\<]*\<\/h1\>/', $code)
);
array_shift($content);

// Headings array...
preg_match_all('/\<h1\>[^\<]*\<\/h1\>/', $code, $matches);
$headings = $matches[0];

// Result
$result = array(
    'headings' => $headings,
    'content'  => $content,
);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [headings] => Array
        (
            [0] => <h1>Heading</h1>
            [1] => <h1>Heading 2</h1>
        )

    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  <p>Paragraph</p><ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph</p>
            [1] =>  <ul><li>List item</li><li>List item</li></ul><p>Paragraph<img /></p>
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Helps with my regex skills :)