# Get the table right behind an element

Tags: c#, html, uwp, win-universal-app, html-agility-pack

I want to get the table which is located right behind a element:

```
<body>
    <h3>test</h3>
    <table>
        <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
    </table>

    <h3>test2</h3>
    <table>
        <tr><td>def</td></tr>
    </table>
    [...]
</body>
```

So I only want to get the table after the h3 element "test" (or the content of the table but I know how to do this kind of stuff).
The table "test" isn't always first, could also be somewhere after the seconds table.

---

**[Edit]**

Do you know why this code:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html); //your test html
var s = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Where(_ => _.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Name.Equals("h3") && _.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.InnerText.Equals("test"));
foreach (var st in s)
{
     Debug.WriteLine(st.InnerHtml);
}
```

doesn't work if I remove the return after "/h3" and "table"?

It looks like this:

```
string html = @"<body><h3>test</h3><table><tr><td>abc</td></tr></table><h3>test2</h3><table><tr><td>def</td></tr></table></body>"
```

instead of the html code above but the result is null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. I find Linq is more handy. It's just an idea you can expand it further or just post your issue here, we can work it out :).
Sorry I didn't have IDE with me.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html); //your test html
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Where(_ => _.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Name.Equals("h3"));
```

Btw, the reason we need to call previousSibling twice is there is always 1 #text element between each nodes.

Comment: But how do I search for the text in h3 (test)? Because I got two h3's

Comment: Something like this? `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Where(_ => _.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Name.Equals("h3") && _.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.InnerText.Equals("test"));`

Comment: Do you have the answer of my edited question? Would be very helpfull to know

Comment: Just remove 1 PreviousSibling call. 
            `var s = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Where(_ => _.PreviousSibling.Name.Equals("h3") && _.PreviousSibling.InnerText.Equals("test"));`

Comment: Oh, simple and make sense :D. Thx

Comment: You may want to write a recursive function to look for h3 element in sibling collection. Above code is just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something for XPath:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html); //your test html
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[text()='test']/following::table");
return table.InnerHtml; //returns: "\r\n        <tr><td>abc</td></tr>\r\n    "
```

XPath from: [XPath - Select first element after some other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276753/xpath-select-first-element-after-some-other-element#1276826)

EDIT: Picture of exact code:
[image]

EDIT 2:
Your problem is that there is not necessarily a text element involved. Thus you can solve this by putting a check for that:

```
var table3 = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x =>
            {
                if (x.NodeType == HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (x.PreviousSibling?.NodeType == HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeType.Text)
                    {
                        return x.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling?.Name == "h3" && x.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling?.InnerText == "test";
                    } else
                    {
                        return x.PreviousSibling?.Name == "h3" && x.PreviousSibling?.InnerText == "test";
                    }
                }
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: For me it unfortunately doesn't work. I have to open a foreach loop so I can access table.InnerHtml (table is an arrey, not sure about this but something like this).

Comment: but it still returns null

Comment: Weird, I tested this before and SelectSingleNode returns a single HtmlNode. I'll post a picture of the exact code I used so we're clear about that

Comment: Oh, ok. The only thing I can think of is that I develop a windows 10 app. I eg had to change .SelectSingleForm to .Descendants.

Comment: Descendants doesn't select by XPath so that wouldn't work. Could you clarify the version of HtmlAgilityPack you're using?

Comment: It is 1.4.9.5 so it should be up to date or?

Comment: Weird, SelectSingleNode has been there since at least 1.3.0, so I don't know why it shouldn't be available for you as well. I believe it may be because System.Xml provides the functions. What's your version for that? (just select the namespace in the references)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132539/discussion-between-eric-van-der-toorn-and-dieter-muller).