# Xpath for non nested (sibling) elements

Tags: xpath

Source Document:

```
<div class='master'>
 <div class='recordBlock' id='gf5rtf4'/>
 <div id='d3dre'>First block</div>
 <div id='fa2s2w'>Second Block</div>
 <div class='recordBlock' id='fred11' />
 <div id='asd423'>Third block</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out xpath for the two div elements under recordBlock with id gf5rtf4,that is to say divs with ids d3dre and fa2s2w only, and not the third div asd423.

This cannot be explicit though because I would also need the same Xpath expression to run against the recordBlock with id fred11 to return element with id asd423.

The  suggested link does not meet the question criteria, the expressed link deals with nested elements, the question I asked presents the problem of non nested elements (at the same level in the hierarchy) but delimited by class=recordBlock with a specified id value to return siblings between the delimit.

I honestly do not even know how to start this, the divs under each recordBlock are conceptually nested but not so in the document (as can be seen)

Comment: These are not *under* (in hierarchy), they are *after* the recordBlock mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath - Select first element after some other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276753/xpath-select-first-element-after-some-other-element)

Comment: No, the suggestion is not sufficient, it deals with nested elements my question is for non-nested elements

Comment: @Phil Can you check my answer and let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath to get the sibling div's between two nodes.

**Using Xpath 1:**

```
//div[@class='master']/div[not(@class = 'recordBlock')][ count(../div[@class='recordBlock'][3]/preceding-sibling::*) = count(preceding-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1] /following-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1]/preceding-sibling::*)]
```

**ScreenShot for Xpath 1:**
[image]

===========================================================================

**Using Xpath 2:**

**Note:** We have replace  <kbd>x</kbd>  with the next recordBlock postion till where you want the divs.

```
//div[@class='master']/div[not(@class = 'recordBlock')][generate-id(../div[@class='recordBlock'][x])= generate-id(preceding-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1]/following-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1])]
```

If you want to get the sibling till the 2nd `recordBlock` (meaning anything between first and second record blocks) check the below xpath.

```
//div[@class='master']/div[not(@class = 'recordBlock')][generate-id(../div[@class='recordBlock'][2]) = generate-id(preceding-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1]/following-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1])]
```

output:
[image]

I know you are thinking what should I give for the last one, just as I mentioned above it's always `+1` so you have to specify as `3` or `any number >2` should work.

```
//div[@class='master']/div[not(@class = 'recordBlock')][generate-id(../div[@class='recordBlock'][3]) = generate-id(preceding-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1]/following-sibling::div[@class='recordBlock'][1])]
```

**output:**
[image]

**Just a side note:** This approach will work irrespective of number of selective nodes (div in this case) between the specified items (`recordBlock` in this case).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
//div[@class="recordBlock"]/following-sibling::div[not(@class)]
```

And the output is...

> First block Second Block Third block

Comment: @zx485 - Not sure what your problem is. OP said he wants to get "divs with ids d3dre and fa2s2w... also need the same Xpath expression to run against the recordBlock with id fred11 to return element with id asd423." So he needs all three siblings, I believe.

Comment: @zx485 - It's not clear to me that having them in one sequences is a problem they way OP phrased the question, but whatever.

Comment: I still do think that my objections were correct. But due to the unclear situation I retract all of them. (Even my downvote, but I cannot do this until you edit your answer).

Comment: @zx485 - I'll do that, though the vote isn't that important: the lesson learned is - make sure I clarify with OP exactly what the desired output is (which I normally do), before I jump in with an answer...

Comment: Well, I don't think that it's necessary to take that fundamental approach. Your answer was a good approach, but not correct. I merely noticed that the answer had a serious flaw. However, I didn't know better... There's no easy solution...