# JS select <ul> tag following an <h2> tag containing "foo"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

So I've got this little chrome extension project and I'm trying to figure out how to find the first "ul" element on the page that comes after an "h2" element that contains a particular word.

Example of what the web page would look like...

```
<div>
  <h2>Foo</h2> // find the first <h2> tag containing "Foo"
  <ul></ul> // find the first <ul> tag that comes after the <h2>  
</div>
```

However the nature of varying page code means that it may looks more like this...

```
<h2>Foo</h2> // find the first <h2> tag containing "Foo"
<div> 
  <ul></ul> // find the first <ul> tag that comes after the <h2> 
</div>
```

Or even...

```
<div>
  <h2>Foo</h2> // find the first <h2> tag containing "Foo"
</div>
<div>
  <ul></ul> // find the first <ul> tag that comes after the <h2>
</div>
```

I can get the "h2" element containing "foo" by...

```
let hTags = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
let hTag;
for (var i = 0; i < hTags.length; i++) {
    if (/foo/i.test(hTags[i].textContent)) {
        hTag = hTags[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

But that is where I'm stuck, I can't figure out how to search the rest of the DOM that follows the found "h2" tag. Sibling selectors won't work as the "h2" and the "ul" may not be within the same element.

Also being a chrome extension rules out using anything like jQuery.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276753/xpath-select-first-element-after-some-other-element It suggests using xpath, which should have some way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2>Foo</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <script>
      const regex = new RegExp('foo', 'i');
      const foundElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('* H2, UL')];
      const firstUL = foundElements
        .slice(1)
        .find(
          (el, i) => el.tagName === 'UL' && foundElements[i].tagName === 'H2' && regex.test(foundElements[i].innerText)
        );
      console.log(firstUL);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is ace! Exactly what I needed. Any thoughts on how I would adjust it to look for h1, h2 and h3 tags containing "foo"?

Comment: If you would like it to look for ULs after H1, H2 or H3 tags containing "foo", you should simply change the selector to: .querySelectorAll('* H1, H2, H3, UL')